# Passing Hex parameter to RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have an RDLC report in my project where a text field is passed a string parameter using the following method to generate a hex number;

```
public string GetHexColor(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        return string.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", r, g, b);
    }
```

I was hoping for the user to specify the color of the fill by using this however, when I generate the report I recieve the message that the parameter is missing a value.

```
ReportParameter pPartType = new ReportParameter("pPartType", currentPart.partType);
ReportParameter fLabelHex = new ReportParameter("fLabelHex", partType.GetHexColor(partType.label_R, partType.label_G, partType.label_B).ToLower());
ReportParameter fTextHex = new ReportParameter("fTextHex", partType.GetHexColor(partType.text_R, partType.text_G, partType.text_B).ToLower());
```

[image]

Comment: Where do you actually pass the parameters?

Comment: Of course, I defined the parameter but forgot to pass it through to "reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters", also I had to add a # to the beginning of the  GetHexColor string. Thank you